# QTP Webtable exists but RO properties are empty when traversed twice through descriptive programming

Tags: qtp

I am using QTP 11 with Win 7 and IE 9.
I am trying to automate an application using descriptive programming.
The problem I am facing is that there is a `webtable` on a screen. I have to access its contents more than once in the complete workflow.

When I get the rowcount for the first time it returns a proper value but after performing some other steps when I again try to traverse the `webtable` its exist property is true but the RO properties are empty.

If i use simply the rowcount method QTP throws an error `Unspecified error` but if I use `GetRoProperty("rows")` to get value in a variable the value displayed is empty in the watch window of the debugger.

The issue here is that the `webtable` is right on the screen and if I use Object Repository then the code works fine but using descriptive programming is giving me hard time.

If I take the rowcount after exiting the complete workflow then it returns the correct value.
Only thing is that if I run two modules simultaneously then its failing but if I run them individually then everything is working fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am pretty sure this user will never return, and this well-answered question will this never be accepted. What should happen to questions like these? They suck big time.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like you are storing a reference to the WebTable object on the first pass, navigating away from the page on which the WebTable exists, and then coming back to that page later in the workflow (or refreshing the page). You are then trying to access the object properties via the stored variable. Correct?

If so, you can't do this. You need to reacquire the reference to the WebTable when you return to the page. I imagine you'd run into the same problem if you stored a reference to the OR object in a variable and tried to reuse it in the same manner.

In other words, you can't do this:

```
set x = Browser().Page().WebTable("some descriptive programming") 'same if this was an OR definition
print x.RowCount
'Navigate to another page
'Do stuff
'Navigate back to the page with the WebTable
print x.RowCount
```

**Edit:** As [TheBlastOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355294/theblastone) helpfully reminded me, the preferred solution these days is to call .RefreshObject:

```
set x = Browser().Page().WebTable("some descriptive programming")
print x.RowCount
'Navigate to another page
'Do stuff
'Navigate back to the page with the WebTable
x.RefreshObject ' <== REACQUIRE
print x.RowCount
```

As an alternative to RefreshObject you could to do this:

```
set x = Browser().Page().WebTable("some descriptive programming")
print x.RowCount
'Navigate to another page
'Do stuff
'Navigate back to the page with the WebTable
set x = Browser().Page().WebTable("some descriptive programming") ' <== REACQUIRE
print x.RowCount
```

Using the OR definition each time would also work fine as you mention:

```
print Browser().Page().WebTable("MyTable").RowCount
'Navigate to another page
'Do stuff
'Navigate back to the page with the WebTable
print Browser().Page().WebTable("MyTable").RowCount
```